# Selenium webtest, fails opening same dropdown again (2/3rd operation) in Run mode, but Passes in Debug mode

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a scenario to Create, Edit, Delete an operation, by selecting a value from the dropdown in a single Selenium webtest (using C#, in Chrome Browser).

**Issue:**

Webtest clicks a dropdown and selects a value for the 'Create' operation (1st time), but for the 'Edit' operation (2nd time), the same dropdown is not clicked to select a value from it.

*Note:* This webtest passes if run in Debug mode.
*Anaylsis done:* There is no change in locator of the dropdown. i have even checked with 'WaitForElementToBeEnabled', 'WaitForElementToBeDisplayed', 'Thread.sleep'it doesn't work.

Please share your thoughts on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code? Both HTML and Selenium. Is it an HTML `<select>` or simulated through CSS and JavaScript? Does selecting the 'Create' operation modify the page in any way (thus possibly changing the location/locator)?

Comment: Please find the C# code below:  
      
private void OpenValueDropDown()
        {
            this.Handler.Click(TsBy.Css("div [class *='selected-node-field']"));
            this.WaitForElementToBeEnabled(TsBy.Css("div[class *='selected-node-field opened']"));
         }

i have also validated that there is no change in the code/locator/location after the first validation.
Please suggest.